# Getting different city name If location is same in google place autocomplete address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have implemented bellow Google Place Autocomplete Address from my project and I am getting some strange results on this search:

If I search: `Avenida da Liberdade, Lisbon, Portugal`

```
City is: Lisboa
State is: Lisboa
```

[image]

and If I search with: `Lisbon, Portugal`

```
City is: Lisbon
State is: Lisbon
```

[image]

Why I am getting diffrent city, state where location is same.

I have also checked with `bing autocomplete` and I am getting same city and state with above two search results. Check here: [bing autocomplete](http://matthaeuskrenn.com/addressautocomplete/)

Here I am attaching my JSFiddle for testing perpose: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mananpatel/41f4v57p/1/)

Any Idea about this variation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to localize your map if you want to get results in a specific language.

Here is the [list of supported languages](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport).

So if you want to get `Lisboa` for both requests, you can localize it to Portuguese (Portugal) with the `pt-PT` code:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&language=pt-PT
```

Problem is, if you want English (or another language) in both results, it doesn't work.

Searching for `Lisbon, Portugal` will return `Lisbon` but searching for anything local — like a street name — will return `Lisboa, Portugal`.

I don't know if this can be considered as a bug but it could be worth reporting it. I don't see anything about this behavior in the [localization documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization).

**Edit**:

Bug report: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7891

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/5jso4rup/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but we need to find address from all over the world. We cant fix with `language=pt-PT`.

Comment: Hello MrUpsidown. I understand your answer but Is there any solution regarding my question? I want to search location from all over the world.

Comment: What's your goal? In what language do you want to see the results?

Comment: I am working on real estate project and the project is for all countries. I cant fix `language=` for particular country.

Comment: You still didn't answer my question. *In what language do you want to see the results?*

Comment: I want to see the result in english language.

Comment: Well then you fall in the case of the bug that was reported. I don't have a solution for that. As you can see, the bug report has been accepted.